# When changing \arraystretch and nesting tabular-environments, vertical gaps occur in the resulting table. How do those come into being?

Tags: tables, vertical-spacing

Minimal compilable example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|}
\hline
\begin{tabular}{c|c}A&B\end{tabular}&\begin{tabular}{c|c}C&D\end{tabular}\\
\hline
\begin{tabular}{c|c}E&F\end{tabular}&\begin{tabular}{c|c}G&H\end{tabular}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Output when compiling with pdflatex:

[image]

The questions are in the picture:

- How do the vertical gaps below the horizontal lines come into being?
- Why are the four corners of the table blank?

(I am not asking how to fix this.
I am asking why/how these things come into being.)

---

When leaving `\arraystretch` unchanged, the vertical gaps appear at the horizontal bottom-lines:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|@{}c@{}|}
\hline
\begin{tabular}{c|c}A&B\end{tabular}&\begin{tabular}{c|c}C&D\end{tabular}\\
\hline
\begin{tabular}{c|c}E&F\end{tabular}&\begin{tabular}{c|c}G&H\end{tabular}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The inner tablars are not [t]...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard latex `tabular` makes `|` have no no horizontal space, they have a negative skip of half the rule width either side, so you always get a notch in the corners. If you use `array` package the negative spacing is not used and `|` contribute their natural width.

Tabular spacing is implemented by adding a strut to each row, and arraystretch works by increasing the size of the strut. The normal case, as here, is that the height of the strut is larger than the height of the cell content and so prevents the cell content touching a hline above the row.

Answer (score 0):

This might explain how the vertical gaps come into being:

[image]